# Remote reset circuit does not work

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, reset

I have a custom board based on an Atmega168A which I would like to reset when the power switch to the on-board LEDs is switched off.

Resetting the uC by shorting RST and GND works on the ICSP connector (sanity check), but switching off the power switch SW1 when 5V is present does not. At least rarely. I did manage to make it work a few times, but it was shortly after I had shorted RESET and GND so it *happened* to work.

Here is the reset subcircuit, where both the USB data connector and 5V power supply are present, as well as the ICSP. It is supposed to be an adaptation of a typical DTR reset... (note +5V is separated from +5V_USB)
[image]

Here is what happened when the LED power was switched off, i.e. when the switch connects the net named +5V to 0V instead of the external 5V supply:
[image]

I modelled the subcircuit in LTspice just in case and proceeded to modify it to try something different - I needed a pull-down resistor between +5V and 0V USB anyway to monitor the presence of +5V from the Atmega (which I had forgotten): increased C6 to 330nF, removed short between +5V and 0V_USB when the switch is OFF, added R6=1k.
[image]
And the result: now the pulses are systematic regardless of whether I manually reset using the ICSP right before, but they're way too high for a reset at 2.4V !
[image]

LTSpice (and in fact, a simple calculation of resistor divider) says the pulse should go down to 0.6V... What's happening? RESET pins are supposed to have internal pull-ups in the order of 30k min, not 1k...
[image]

What would be an easy fix for this circuit (robust still) with as few additional components (if possible passives) as possible (the PCB is quite dense)?

Comment: What are your input high and low limits?  Also, is there a spec for the minimum time reset needs to be held low?

Comment: While the "electrical characteristics" says 0.2Vcc or 1V, a graph of Vil(Reset) vs Vcc says 2.2V. I do not know the time low required, but I expect it to be quite low since I managed to reset it with 250us.

Comment: I would suggest that he *simplest* method would be a voltage monitor with a reset output such as https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/supervisors-voltage-monitors-sequencers/MAX6854.html to take your existing pulse and drive a hard reset.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've edited my last question though, I'd like to stick to very few passives as I have a low footprint/low cost constraint. Also, I'd like to understand what's going on, since it's supposed to be a "typical DTR reset circuit"...

Comment: It looks like the internal glitch / spike filter (page 57) combined with the pull up resistor is the probable issue. The filter will reject anything up to 2.5 usec (see table 29.11) which is a really long time as far as glitch filters go. Without knowing the implementation details I can only speculate that this is an RC type filter. The range of reset thresholds leads me to believe this may be the case (0.6V to 1.6V)

Comment: Interesting - how do you explain the fact that the min voltage was 1V in the first case where there was no pull-down resistor?

Comment: @MisterMystère Have you checked the populated resistor for R5 is really a 10K resistor, not a 1K?

Comment: Yes, I paid attention to using a 10k resistor when populating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming your 5V supply goes immediately to zero when disconnected.  In reality, it will fall slowly as LEDs have some capacitance, and they stop conducting substantially once the voltage across them is below their rated forward voltage.

In addition, you have current from both the 10K and internal pullups which largely has to go through your 1K pulldown.  As a result, until the capacitor is charged, you have a voltage divider which will keep the voltage across the 1K higher than 0V.

I'd suggest putting the capacitor and a ~100K-1M resistor in parallel with one side to ground, and attaching the other side to the unused terminal on the switch.  The capacitor will discharge to 0V while the unit is powered, and when you remove power, you drain the +5V circuit to near 0V (depending on the LED capacitances) until the capacitor charges.  You may have to adjust the cap value.

Comment: Eagle eye. I forgot to disconnect the LED strips from the +5V supply to see if the problem vanished - just did that, and the pulse looks much more like the one in the simulation. I had 147 WS2812B LEDs on that line, that's 14.7uF so that may be the reason. Since by simulation it seems your solution would require 100uF, I ended up getting the reset pulse from the connector end of the switch, i.e. pulse low when the connector is unplugged. I still don't know exactly what's going on, because I tried to add a 14.7uF between +5V and 0V_USB and I can't reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Maybe use all that capacitance to your advantage...instead of hooking up +5V to your reset line, connect it to the drain of an NMOSFET, source to ground, gate to unused switch terminal.  When you switch off, the stored charge turns the FET on long enough to reset the ATMega.  A resistor from gate to source could be adjusted to dial in the reset time, as well as keeping the FET off while +5V is on.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that on my prototype. Cheers!

Comment: I realized I was unclear above...the drain goes to the reset line, not +5V.